# SWT Multiple Monitor Support on Solaris?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, solaris, rcp

I am writing an application in Java using SWT. On our Solaris machines, we have multiple monitor setups, but they are treated in isolation by the operating system. This means I can't open the application and drag it to another monitor. The right-click context menu doesn't even allow me to change the monitor the application is displayed on.

What I want to do is provide a way for the user to "send" all or part of my SWT shell to another monitor. How can I do this?

*Additional Information*
A call to Display.getMonitors() returns Monitor[] but the length is 1 (when it should be 2 or 3 or ... N monitors.)

Comment: What do you mean by treated in isolation by the operating system: i.e how the user select the monitor he wants to use for other applications ?

Comment: basically, he means that you can't move an application to another monitor. it can move between workspaces on that monitor, though.

Comment: What I mean by isolation is that the applications you are running are "stuck" on a single monitor such that you cannot drag the window to a secondary monitor. Some applications have a context menu available to "send" the window to other monitors, but applications built with Eclipse/SWT do not. I was able to solve this problem in SWT/AWT but that does me little good since our existing application is entirely in SWT and I doubt there is intention to change that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What eclipse version are you using?

According to [bug 209039](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=209039), "this" (i.e. "`Display.getMonitors()` returning only one monitor") is fixed since 3.4M4 for SWT on Solaris.

As mentioned by  [Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53897/thorbjorn-ravn-andersen) in the comments, [eclipse3.4.2 is available on OpenSolaris](http://pkg.opensolaris.org/release/en/search.shtml?token=eclipse&action=Search).

Comment: Eclipse 3.4.2 is available from the package repository in OpenSolaris.  I believe both the SPARC and x86 version are also regularily built by the Eclipse compile farm.

Comment: Thanks to the both of you, this was good information. We're apparently running a slightly older version of SWT and since we're running out of time before the next build release, we'll have to push the upgrade to a later time. Hopefully then I'll be able to make this multimonitor stuff work!